# How to get all block and floated elements in same line?

Tags: css

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/fGWuN/3/

HTML

```
<div>
<h4 class="pro-price">€135.57</h4>
<a class="order-button" href="javascript:void(0)">Order<span></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {float:right; border: 1px solid red}
h4 {float:left; dispaly:inline-block}
a {float:left; display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the floats and fix the typo for "display".

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fGWuN/4/)

Comment: don't know why in my actually still it's not working. Parent div is taking less width then its element

Comment: Interesting.. works fine in the fiddle. Perhaps there's some other CSS at play?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div {float: right; border: 1px solid red}
h4  {float: left; display:inline}
a   {float: left; display:inline; padding: 20px 0 0 20px; }
```